# How do I replace an empty form field with a 0 in order to prevent NaN in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

HTML

```
<input type='text' id='costs' value='100' size='3'></input>
```

JQuery

```
var costs = $("#costs");
var c = parseFloat(costs.val().replace(",",".")); //germany ;)
costs.text(c);
```

If I leave the input field empty I get NAN. What do I have to change to replace the input field with a 0 if it is empty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var val = costs.val().replace(",","."),
c = isNaN(val) ? 0 : parseFloat(val);
```

Answer (score 1):

Capture the form submit. Find all inputs and check if the text is empty, if so, add a '0'.

```
$('#form').submit(function(){
  var theInputs = $(this).find('input');
  $.each(theInputs, function(i,obj){
    if($(obj).text() == ''){ //we could have checked for empty. I checked for no string.
      $(obj).text('0');
      return true; //let the form continue with the submit.
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your user-case but, You could just do a simple check for `NaN` and set it to 0.

Like this:

```
$("#set").click(function(){
    var costs = $("#costs");
    var c = parseFloat(costs.val().replace(",",".")); //germany ;)
    alert(c);
    if(!isNaN(c)) {
        costs.val(c);
    } else {
        costs.val("0");
    }
});
​
```

Html:

```
<input type='text' id='costs' value='100' size='3'></input>
<button id="set">Set</button>
```

See a working demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/jBeN9/

If you want the code to look real terse you could use a ternary operator like this, **it's the same thing**. :

```
$("#set").click(function(){
    var costs = $("#costs");
    var c = parseFloat(costs.val().replace(",",".")); //germany ;)
    costs.val((isNaN(c) ? "0" : c));
});
```

​

Comment: Thankyou for your efforts, hmmmm, the code on jsfiddle does replace the NaN only after the second try...strange...

Answer (score 1):

If you want replace the NaN with 0, just write this:

```
var c = parseFloat(costs.val().replace(",",".")) || 0;
```